# return column names along with result in oracle select query- to export to excel

Tags: excel, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-excel

I need to get the column names in the result set in oracle select query. When i copy the result set in `Oracle SQL Developer` to excel only the data gets copied. not column names.

I know i can use `dba_tab_columns` to get the column information of a table but i want a way to include it in the row format with the result.
Also i do not want to hard code the column names with a `union` query as there are many tables i need to take and lot of columns.

Export option also doesnt work for me as i am connecting to a remote server using Citrix. so it saves to the remote machine path. not the local path

Comment: Export also gives you an option of copying the data to clipboard in the desired format ,just click the export button ,choose the desired format and select save as to clipboard

Comment: Awsome. thats exactly what i wanted thanks.

Comment: "Export option also doesnt work for me (...)" ... What?

Comment: sorry there was typing mistake. i meant remote path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SQL Developer** provides a lot of options. And you might be missing something, else the **Export** option to **save the query result as Excel** does the job.

1. Run statement ( Ctrl + Enter)
2. Right click on the **Query Result** and select **Export**

[image]

3. In the **Export Wizard**, select **excel 2003 +(xlsx)** and make sure the check box of **Header** is ticked.

[image]

Comment: yes i do have the option . but as i run from remote machine i am unable to choose a local drive/map drive because of the restrictions.

Comment: Why can't you connect it from client and save it there?

Comment: Thanks. as mentioned in the questions comments . I can export to a clipboard instead of file. Then it can be copied to a local file.

Comment: Select Export- Select 'Text' in Format- Select 'Clipboard' in Save As.- Finish- Paste in excel

Answer (score 2):

You can use the UNION trick:

```
SELECT 'column1',
       'column2',
       'column3',
       1 AS x
  FROM yourTable
UNION
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       column3,
       2 AS x
  FROM yourTable
ORDER BY x;
```

If the number of columns is huge then you can use the `dba_tab_columns` to get the column names from your table and do the `UNION` logic.

Answer (score 1):

There's an awesomely easy way to achieve what you want. If I got you right, you copy/paste the results to excel, right?

However, if you want to have the full data (including the column names), you just have to execute your query as a script.

There's a button "Execute script" next to the "normal" "play button".

[image]

You'll get something like this as the result:

```
C1                      C2                            C3                        C4     C5
---------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------- ----- ------ 
8                      SOMETHING                       1337                      A     1337
```

You are able to copy this output completely in your clipboard ans paste it in excel.

Comment: Yes i use this too. but as the data is in text format there is some formatting issues like all headers goes in to the same cell .